# SAPUI5 - How to keep two models in sync

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5, I want to know how to keep two models in sync. I am using sap.ui.getCore().setModel() and sap.ui.getCore().getModel(), to pass on data between two controller and between a controller and it's view. Now if I change model data in one controller, how can I get updated in second Controller or View.

Below is the sample code structure.

I have a customControl

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("CustomControl", {      // call the new Control type "my.Hello" 
                                          // and let it inherit from sap.ui.core.Control
metadata : {                              // the Control API
    properties : {
        ....
        "dataProvider": {type : "any", defaultValue: new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel()},
        ....
    },},
render:function() {
//I am using dataProvider as a model for the Table which is inside this CustomControl

}}
```

In view I am using that CustomControl as this

```
 var oCustomCotrol = new CustomControl("XYZ",{....dataProvider: this.getModel("ModelData"),....});
```

In Controller I am setting up the ModelData

```
onInit: function() {
        console.log("Init update Market");
        var responseData = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        // Ajax call to fetch the data assign it to reponseData,
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(responseData,"ModelData")
},
```

Data is being changed but table in CustomControl is not getting updated

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is... if you change data in a model stored in the core, and both views/controllers make use of that model, the changes are reflected in both views/controllers as well

Comment: Never seen a JSONModel being used inside a custom control... not sure if your approach will work. Instead, why not use the standard approach and bind the `dataProvider` property to an array -- the array being a property of your outside model

Comment: @Qualiture Thanks for your response, using bindProperty gives me some error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined", may be it gets stuck in lifecycle of component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you simply create one or more models and set them either on the core or on the component (latter one for component based apps). After that the models are visible in the complete app/component. So there is no need to manually sync multiple models, because you have one or more models visible everywhere. When the model is changed in one controller then the change is visible everywhere automatically because the model is visible everywhere. That's it.

I think you should start by reading some SAPUI5 tutorials. Here are two good ones:

1. [Walkthrough Tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html)
2. [Data Binding Tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c.html)

The walkthrough is a good start for anyone. The Data Binding Tutorial will focus on Data binding, i.e. you will learn more about models etc.

Maybe this gives you a hint of how to do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Demo</title>

    <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" 
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

    <script>
      
      jQuery.sap.declare("nabisoft.demo.CustomControl");
      sap.ui.core.Control.extend("nabisoft.demo.CustomControl", {
          metadata: {
              properties: {
                  title: {type: "string"}
              }
          },
          renderer : {
              render : function(oRm, oControl) {
                  oRm.write("<div");
                  oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
                  oRm.write(">");

                  oRm.write("<h1>");
                  oRm.write(oControl.getTitle());
                  oRm.write("</h1>");
                                         
                  oRm.write("</div>");
              }
          }
      });      
      
      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
          theTitle : "Some Title"
      });
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"modelName")
      
      //show it works with javascript      
      var oControl   = new nabisoft.demo.CustomControl({
          title:"{modelName>/theTitle}"
      });
      oControl.placeAt("content");
      
    </script>  
 
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nabi, I just updated my question to be more precise. Please have a look at it and let me know if my question is more clear.

Comment: There is no need to have a property in a custom control for your model! Every element /control can make use of the powerful data binding features that UI5 offers you. Again, please read the tutorials! The walkthrough even handles custom controls a little bit. You could also check my UI5 tutorials at  https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/, especially have a look at https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/creating-custom-controls-in-sapui5 . As you will see there is absolutely no need of such a property in custom controls that hold the model itself!!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. above examples work well when you are binding a string to a label in a component, but when I try bind a model of a table(which is inside component), to a model in a view it doesnt work. What I am trying to achieve is a common component for the table, where developers pass the Header information and the key of the response JSON to be mapped with header. And then give the Model reference, and table should be drawn. I am able to pass the data in synchronous manner means if I fetch data first and then assign it component then it is fine other way round is nt wrking

Comment: Of course this component will be having few more controls, which are needed. So I want to keep them in one custom control. Sorry for too much of commets

Comment: I think this all has nothing to do with the initial question. Furthermore, I think you should read the tutorials from the links I gave you. Also, you should post some example code that clearly illustrates your issue!!! Using the dataProvider the way you are using it in your code is not the idea of UI5. Sorry to tell you that. Ever thought about using an aggregation "table" in your custom control and then using bindAggregation(), and also bindItems() on the table??? This is my last answer to this question as this is a little off topic compared to the initial question. Sorry.

Comment: @Nabi is right; you should **not** use a JSONModel inside your custom control

Comment: @Nabi , Thanks, I was able to sort it out with your help and using setModel of the component. Now i am able to get updates in the component.